# Should a landmark element have an aria-label when it also has an heading inside of it?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

A screen reader user has multiple options to access content on the page.
A list of all headings for example, but also a list of landmarks.
With `aria-label`, you can label a landmark.

Consider the following markup:

```html
<main>
  <h1>My Blog items</h1>
  
  <article aria-label="Why blueberries tast good">
    <h2>Why blueberries tast good</h2>
    <p>Some content about blueberries</p>
    <a href="/why-blueberries-test-good">Read more</a>
  </article>
  
  <article aria-label="I don't like apples">
    <h2>I don't like apples</h2>
    <p>Text about why I don't like apples</p>
    <a href="/i-dont-like-apples">Read more</a>
  </article>
  
   <article aria-label="Oranges are orange">
    <h2>Oranges are orange</h2>
    <p>An article discussing the color of fruit</p>
    <a href="/oranges-are-orange">Read more</a>
  </article>
</main>
```

Are the `aria-label`s in the above example useful to a screen reader user, or are they overkill?

Comment: I know examples are meant to be minimal but is that meant to be a list of articles that link to other articles (in which case can you add the `<a>` elements) or is it that the articles are displayed in full on the same page one after the other. Depending on what you are doing the `aria-labels` may be good or bad here.

Comment: Good point, I had an overview of blog posts in mind. So the <p> elements are an excerpt of the blogpost. I will update the example with a link to the fictive blog posts.
You state that: Depending on what you are doing the `aria-labels` may be good or bad
Could you explain when and why they are bad or when and why they are good?

Comment: Tried my best to answer that as well for you in the answer below and explain why I was asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The behaviour of `aria-label` is the key to understanding when to use it.

So in the comments I asked whether these were posts inline in the page or excerpts linking to other pages.

The reason this is important is down to the behaviour of `aria-label`.

If you add `aria-label` to a container **it will over-ride all of the content in that container**.

So if these were just full articles the `aria-label` would replace the whole blog content.

#### Example 1 - actual articles on the page

For example:

```
<article aria-label="Why blueberries taste good">
    <h2>Why blueberries taste good</h2>
    <p>Some content about blueberries which could be hundreds of paragraphs long</p>
 </article>
```

Would only be read as "Why blueberries taste good" and all of the post content would be lost for screen reader users. (Kind of, obviously active elements such as links etc. still get read out and are accessible so it isn't straight forward but hopefully you get the idea).

As such in the above example the `aria-label` should be removed.

#### Example 2 - whole article is a link

Now if this was a list of posts with excerpts that are surrounded in a hyperlink we may not want the excerpt text read out as part of the hyperlink text.

For example:-

```
<article>
    <a href="somewhere" aria-label="Why blueberries taste good">
        <h2>Why blueberries taste good</h2>
        <p>Some content about blueberries which could be hundreds of paragraphs long</p>
    </a>
 </article>
```

In the above example the whole article excerpt is part of the hyperlink text so we may decide it is better to override this and just have the article title as the link text.

However see the "final thoughts" section as I still think there is a preferable way to do this.

### Your Example

In the example you gave I would not use `aria-label` at all.

Now this is partially down to the behaviour of `aria-label` as stated previously but more importantly down to how screen reader users navigate pages.

Screen readers have shortcuts for listing all the links on a page, cycling through headings and cycling through sections. This is the way that screen reader users "orientate" themselves and explore pages and the contents of the page.

Your example way of doing things is nice and accessible. Screen reader users can navigate by sections (`<article>`), headings `<h2>` or by hyperlinks.

Adding an `aria-label` is actually worse for screen reader users as they may or may not (depending on the screen reader and browser combination) be able to access the `<h2>`s anymore as you have overridden them.

#### Example 3 - same as yours but with the `aria-label` removed

```
<article>
    <h2>Oranges are orange</h2>
    <p>An article discussing the color of fruit</p>
    <a href="/oranges-are-orange">Read more</a>
  </article>
```

### Proper use of aria-label

`aria-label` is used to add information where there isn't any (or to add contextual information portrayed visually in certain circumstances).

For example if you have social media icons as links to your social media channel then adding an `aria-label` is one way to allow the accessibility tree to provide meaningful information to a screen reader.

Use it sparingly and always think of `aria-label` as **a last resort** after you have exhausted all semantically appropriate options.

### Final Thoughts on the above examples

I personally would use `aria-hidden` instead of `aria-label` for example 2 (where we have a list of articles where the whole article is a link).

So instead I would structure those as follows:

```
<article>
        <a href="somewhere">
            <h2>Why blueberries taste good</h2>
            <!--using `aria-hidden` on the excerpt text so that the `<h2>` is more likely to be discoverable using headings shortcuts-->
            <div aria-hidden="true">
                <p>Some content about blueberries which could be hundreds of paragraphs long</p>
            </div> 
        </a>
     </article>
```

The reason for this is (as mentioned previously) we are now not potentially over-riding the `<h2>` so in all screen readers the user should now be able to discover this article via heading as well as hyperlink.

Comment: This part: "Screen readers have shortcuts for listing all the links on a page, cycling through headings and cycling through sections. This is the way that screen reader users "orientate" themselves and explore pages and the contents of the page." Is exactly why I asked the question. When a screenreader user orientate themselves via the landmarks, all they see is a list of articles. Articles without context. So maybe I should reprase my question to: How do I give that list of articles context?

Comment: You have context via the page URL, page title, page H1 and the fact it is a list of `<articles>`. It doesn't need any more context than that really. You could add them to an `<ul>` so that the number of articles is read out. If you had multiple article "types" on the same page you could use `aria-describedby` to add extra info such as the article category but that again is overkill in most simple lists of articles.

Comment: "Would only be read as 'Why blueberries taste good' and all of the post content would be lost for screen reader users." Do you have a citation for this? Neither MDN or the ARIA spec indicate that this is the intended behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Not overkill -- but you can use `aria-labelledby` to reference the header's ID to avoid text duplication.